# WSUS WUServerURL not updating in registry (Group Policy)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, wsus

I've just finished setting up a WSUS server to manage our Windows Updates.

Sadly, our previous tech guy set up the WSUS server on our primary domain controller and set up the group policy to point to that.

The WSUS server was removed from our domain controller and I've changed the group policy settings to point to our new one.

However, when i check in the registry for WUServer its still pointing to our old one, not our new one.

If i run `gpupdate /force` it doesn't appear to pull down the new values for the WSUS server

If i change the registry values manually, it resets itself back and now I'm kind of lost, any help would be greatly appreciated.

If i use the group policy modelling wizard, this too uses the old value, not the new one

Our setup consists of 2 servers, 1 as a primary domain controller the other and a secondary (unsure if we actually need this kinda setup for the numbers we have here)

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another Group Policy overrides this value.

From one of the servers, run the following command as administrator: `gpresult /h c:\temp\gpo.html` (you can change the path).

This command will create a group policy report and save it as .HTML file.

Then, you'll be able to see clearly which GPO sets which settings.